# Trying to make my click button show results at all times not just when clicked

Tags: javascript, button, click, counter, display

Right now I have a click button (or a "like" button that's an image heart called .download png) that only displays the click button result number counter when you click on it. I'm trying to get the button to display the result all the time, not just when you click on it, but still up the counter by one when clicked on. Here's the code I have so far in the header:

```
<script>
function clickCounter() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.firstButtonCount) {
            localStorage.firstButtonCount = Number(localStorage.firstButtonCount)+1;               
        } else {
            localStorage.firstButtonCount = 1; 
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.firstButtonCount; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }

}
</script>
```

And then the body code:

```
<p>
    <button type="button" onclick="clickCounter()">
        <div class="number" id="result"></div>
        <img src="download.png" width="50px" height="auto class="clickCounter()" type="button alt="Like"/>
    </button>
</p>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but if anyone could show me how to display the result at all times that would be awesome!

Comment: First, check your html markup, it is wrong, i see lot of errors here: `<img src="download.png" width="50px" height="auto class="clickCounter()" type="button alt="Like"/>`. Maybe this should be like this: `<img src="download.png" width="50px" height="auto" />`

Comment: Okay good to know. Thank you! I switched that out but it still doesn't display the counter at all times, just when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note :

To get a value in localStorage ,  you use the method getItem.

To add a value in localStorage , you use the method setItem.

Refer to this article for more https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-local-storage-with-javascript/

Replace your code with this one below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="pt-br">
            <meta charset="utf-8" />

            <head>
                <title>Vote</title>

            </head>

            <body>
                <p>
                    <button type="button" onclick="clickCounter()">
                        <div class="number" id="result"></div>
                        <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/like-18/32/459-01-512.png" width="50px" height="auto" type="button" alt="Like" />
                    </button>
                </p>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var resultElement = document.getElementById('result');

                    function updateResult() {

                        resultElement.innerText = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('firstButtonCount')) || 0;;

                    }

                    function vote() {
                        // body...
                        newCount = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('firstButtonCount')) + 1 || 0 + 1;

                        localStorage.setItem('firstButtonCount', newCount);

                    }

                    function clickCounter() {
                        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

                            /*
                            to get a value in localStorage ,  you use the method getItem
                            to add a value in localStorage , you use the method setItem
                            */

                            vote();
                            updateResult();

                        } else {
                            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
                        }
                    }

                    updateResult();
                </script>
            </body>

            </html>
```

Comment: That doesn't work either, now there's just no result when clicked and no result displayed

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been playing around with this for days now, I super appreciate your help!!

Comment: I just can't figure out what is the main difference with my **commented code**, but I vote you up, if you find the issue, please tellme. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have made a snippet example for you, beacause of security violations I can't use the local storage feature, but you can enable it on your local development framework and discard the global counter.

```js
var _globalCounter = 0;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = _globalCounter;

function clickCounter()
{
    _globalCounter++;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = _globalCounter;

    // This don't work on snippet because security violation,
    // but it should work on you local development framework.

    /*
    if (typeof(Storage) === "undefined")
    {
        alert("Browser don't support local storage");
        return;
    }
    
    var count = Number(localStorage.getItem("firstButtonCount"));

    if (count && count > 0)
    {
        count++;
        localStorage.setItem("firstButtonCount", count);
    }
    else
    {
        localStorage.setItem("firstButtonCount", 1);
    }

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("firstButtonCount");
    */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" onclick="clickCounter()">    
    <i class="far fa-2x fa-thumbs-up"></i>
    <spam class="number" id="result"></spam>
</button>
```

Comment: Still not working for me :( Now it's not displaying a result at all